# Give a moving effect to the image

Tags: jquery, animation, game-physics

[image: Game snipet]

I want to give a moving effect to this.
Should I add a animated screen or is there some other way to give that effect?

Comment: What kind of moving affect do you want to have? Should the saucer fly toward the moon? Shake about?

Comment: I want it to look like as if the saucer is moving forward

Answer (score 0):

You could use scale within jQuery, a better explanation on web animations can be found here.

http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2015/07/animations-part-1/

--- Here is an example:

Your html could be something simple like,

```
<div id="flying"><img src="/spaceship.png"></div>
```

and then maybe use,

```
var player = document.getElementById('flying').animate([
        { transform: 'scale(4)', opacity: 1, offset: 0 },
        { transform: 'scale(1)', opacity: .5, offset: .3 },
        { transform: 'scale(.3)', opacity: .667, offset: .7875 },
        { transform: 'scale(.2)', opacity: .6, offset: 1 }
      ], {
        duration: 700, //milliseconds
        easing: 'ease-in-out', //'linear', a bezier curve, etc.
        delay: 10, //milliseconds
        iterations: Infinity, //or a number
        direction: 'reverse', //'normal', 'reverse', etc.
        fill: 'forwards' //'backwards', 'both', 'none', 'auto'
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following by editing your picture to create 3 different pictures and then uploading those three to a free online gif maker.

[image]

Comment: not exactly what I am looking for.
I want the an animation so that it gives a feeling that the UFO is moving forward.
I have given control to the played to move the UFO but it looks static

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do. You wanted it to move forward? This approach (though my quick attempt is crude) makes it move forward.